# Using SendObject in Access 2013 VBA, using email in table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am super new at this and need help.  I am trying to send a query as an excel document to specific people contained in a table called "tblRelationship", the email is in a field called "Email".  However, there are more people in this table then I want to send to.  There is a third field called "RelationshipType" that I need to set to = Accounting

I have been using this code that I found:

```
Const stDocName As String = "qryPOAccountingReport"
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim stRecipients As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblRelationship")
With rs
Do While Not .EOF
    stRecipients = stRecipients & ";" & !Email
    .MoveNext
Loop
.Close
End With

If Len(stRecipients) > 0 Then
' discard leading ";"
stRecipients = Mid(stRecipients, 2)
DoCmd.SendObject acQuery, stDocName, acFormatXLS, _
    stRecipients, , , "Thank You for your purchase"
Else
MsgBox "No recipients to email!"
End If

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

And it works great.  I just don't understand how to put the "RelationshipType" criteria in there.  Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Simply, run a query in your [OpenRecrdset()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx) which can take whole tables, stored queries, or SQL Select statements:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Email] FROM tblRelationship" _
                           & " WHERE RelationshipType='Accounting'")
```